# Find a test for $H_{0} : \sigma_{1}^{2} \ne \sigma_{2}^{2}$, against $H_{1} : \sigma_{1}^{2} =\sigma_{2}^{2}$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Consider $X_{1}\dots X_{n} $ ~ $N(a_{1},\sigma_{1}^{2})$ and $Y_{1}\dots Y_{m} $ ~ $N(a_{2},\sigma_{2}^{2})$, and they are independent. We need to find a criteria for $H_{0}:: \sigma_{1}^{2} \ne \sigma_{2}^{2}$.

First of all, let's consider (if $H_{0}$ is true) $\frac{\bar{X}\sqrt{n}}{a_{1}} - \frac{\bar{Y}\sqrt{m}}{a_{2}}$ distributed as $N(0,\sigma^{2}\frac{a_{2}^2 +a_{1}^2}{a_{1}^2a_{2}^2})$, then after considering of $\dfrac{\frac{\bar{X}\sqrt{n}}{a_{1}} - \frac{\bar{Y}\sqrt{m}}{a_{2}}}{\sigma\sqrt{\frac{a_1^2 +a_2^2}{a_1^2 a_2^2}}}$. Now we need to estimate $\sigma$ as $S^{2}$, after simplifying we have : 
$\dfrac{\bar{X}\sqrt{n}a_{2} - \bar{Y}\sqrt{m}a_{1}}{\sqrt{a_2^2+a_1^2}S} >t_{1-\alpha /2}$ is a Student-test.

Am I right?

Comment: You don't have to use the student's t-distribution unless your sample is small.

Comment: @Frpzzd actually I'm interested in the correctness of my proof

Comment: What do you mean by "criteria for $H_0$..."? Are you deriving a test for testing $H_0$ against some $H_1$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom yes, it's right to call it a test

Comment: @StubbornAtom added

Comment: Are $a_{1}$ and $a_{2}$ known?

Comment: @LiveFreeorπHard I guess we should suppose they are known

Comment: Generally speaking, no one ever says "build a hypothesis test" without providing further conditions. Is it a most powerful test? A uniformly most powerful test? A likelihood-ratio test? There isn't enough context here. Also, all you've proven is that you have a formula that follows the $t$-distribution. It does not prove that you've constructed a "test."

Comment: @Clarinetist sorry for misunderstandings

Answer (score 1):

I think you're testing the hypothesis $H_0 : \mu_1 = \mu_2$. At least you test statistic seems to suggest so. Mind you, I am only a beginner in this field, so you might be right and I might be wrong. Also, I know only about the equality case (usually the $H_0$ is based on equality, right-tailed, left-tailed or two-tailed). Anyways, here goes

For testing $H_{0} : \sigma_{1}^{2}= \sigma_{2}^{2}$, the appropriate test statistic is

$$F_0 = \frac{S_1^2}{S_2^2}$$

where the reference distribution of $F_0$ is the $F$ distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom for numerator and $m-1$ degrees of freedom for denominator. The null hypothesis would be rejected if $F_0 \gt F_{\alpha/2, n-1,m-1}$ or if  $F_0 \lt F_{1-(\alpha/2), n-1,m-1}$

You can read more about it in the book Design of Experiments by Montgomery, Chapter 2, the ending section.